# Certifications in Careers PDF export

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Is it possible to include certifications for the PDF export of the resume? Here in Peru is very common to have that section in a programming resume.

Comment: You mean "certifications" like the ones from w3schools you better *don't* include in your resume? :p

Comment: Just the ones granted by Oracle or IBM. Some recruiters just LOVE then xD